# g++ building c++ program with boost dependencies

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I want to compile and run a simple c++ websocket application with g++ on windows.

Boost was installed like this:

```
./bootstrap.bat mingw
./b2.exe install --prefix=C:/boostLibs toolset=gcc
```

My c++ includes look like this:

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>

#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>

#include <iostream>
```

This websocket sample was provided by https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp

In order to build the project I issue this command:

```
g++ -Wno-deprecated -I ./cppServer/libs/ -I C:\boostLibs\include\boost-1_55 -L C:\boostLibs\lib -g ./cppServer/server.cpp -lboost_system
```

Which leeds me to this error message:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

If I try to build without *-lboost_system*, I get a very long exception, starting with:

> C:/boostLibs/include/boost-1_55/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>   C:/boostLibs/include/boost-1_55/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
>   C:/boostLibs/include/boost-1_55/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   C:\Users\JOHANN~1.HAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpKMWTH.o: In function`ZN5boost6system10error_codeC1Ev':
>   C:/boostLibs/include/boost-1_55/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   C:\Users\JOHANN~1.HAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpKMWTH.o: In function`ZN5boost6system4errc20make_error_conditionENS1_6errc_tE':
>   C:/boostLibs/include/boost-1_55/boost/system/error_code.hpp:488: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>   C:\Users\JOHANN~1.HAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpKMWTH.o: In function`ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC2EiPKc'

So what am I missing? I can't figure it out right now.

Comment: What are the contents of `C:\boostLibs\lib`?

Comment: Exactly 60 files with an .a ending. Like libboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_55.a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to `boost_system` as `-lboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_55`, because this is what those files are called. See [boost library naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) for more details.

When you build boost you may like to specify `--layout=system` to `b2.exe` so that your files do not have that `-mgw63-mt-1_55`  in the filename and then just use `-lboost_system` when linking against it.

Comment: Ok that helped a little bit. Now there are a lot of errors like: C:/boostLibs/include/boost-1_55/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:82: undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'

Comment: @johni07 You need to link against Microsoft libs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, now there are less error. How do know, that the ms lib was missing?

Comment: @johni07 You use an internet search engine - just google the function name and read the documentation.